# how to set virtual path to go above root directory, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, routes

I am trying to set the virtual path in ASP.NET to go above root directory as follows -

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Test", "test/page", @"~\~\Test\TestPages.aspx");
```

But i am getting the below error -

The resource cannot be found. Http 404.

The TestPages.aspx is one level up compared to Root directory.

Also i have tried - ~..\TestPages.aspx - gives error - Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: If it's outside the application's folder structure, I imagine a client can't request it.  This is for good reason.  You don't want clients to be able to request *any* file on your server's file system.

Comment: Yes it is outside the Main Application. Actually we have multiple apps in our solution. And then finally we have - the Main App Project, which reference all the other Apps. I don't want to add the pages in main project because logically it should belong to a specific App. I can write a small post build script to copy the pages to Applications Main directory. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: I suspect that many environments are like this. Has this question been satisfied Jash?

Comment: @cyclical, post build scripts was the option i choosed